# Including bootstrap in the admin page only

Tags: wordpress, admin

I have added this line on my plugin

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'dazzling-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
```

and it seems that the whole admin backend was affected of that bootstrap. Any ideas on how to be only on that plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not specifying anywhere that the file should be included only for your plugin page, and not for the whole admin backend. Try to add a conditional check and then enqueue the stylesheet.

```
global $post;
if ( 'enter_plugin_page_slug_here' == $post->name ) {

// enqueue stylesheet here

}
```

Comment: 'enter_plugin_page_slug_here' - What do you mean by this? can I have a sample?

Thanks

Comment: How do you register your plugin page? Using `add_plugin_page()` right? That is where you'd have mentioned the page slug for the plugin.